# C++ - How link python library?

Tags: python, c++, hyperlink

Im trying to link python for execute this code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName((wchar_t *)argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
        "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

But I got this error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\test\test\main.cpp|5|undefined reference to `__imp_Py_SetProgramName'|
(....)
```

I linked 'python\include' and 'python\libs', anyone how what I can do?
Im using Codeblocks and MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build with Python headers:

```
g++ main.cpp `python3-config --includes` -o main
```